# Find elementary matrix E

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

For a homework problem, I am required to find an elementary matrix E whcih will be able to perform the row operation R<sub>2</sub> = -3*R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub> on a matrix A of size 3x5 when multiplied from the left, i.e. E*A. I am also required to show my method on how I got E. My problem is that I have not seen a problem like this before and I'm not really sure where to start. I initially came up with a matrix that would require me to perform such a row operation to get it into RREF, but I don't think that's what this problem is looking for. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you take notes in your lectures? Since it's a homework, this should have been discussed in the lectures. Perhaps you can start by reading the notes.

Comment: What do you mean how to write the process? If the process is known - then you should find it immediately no? I mean, it's just performing this row operation on the identity matrix.

Comment: @WhatsUp I always do, but this was not discussed in the lecture at all. My professor is notorious for doing this. I looked up some things on YouTube and they haven't taught me how to do exactly what this professor is wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_{rs}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\  0 & \cdots 
 & 0 & \ddots \end{pmatrix}$

so the only non-zero entry of $I_{rs}$ is placed at r th row and s th column.$I_{rs}A$ simply places s th row at r th row and makes all other entries zero so we can say that

$(I+cI_{rs})A$ changes r th row $R_r$ with $cR_s+R_r$ and doesn`t affect other rows.

The row operation which you want to find is $I-3I_{21}$